# Get choice converted to alphabet in batch

Tags: batch

I want the user to choose an alphabet

```
CHOICE /C A-Z /D D /T 3 /M "Choose an alphabet: "
```

Is there a way to avoid writing all the A-Z and then

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET CHOICE=A
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 SET CHOICE=B
...
```

write all the if conditions to get the choice back as the alphabet from `%ERRORLEVEL%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way where you only need to write out the alphabet once while setting a variable. An extra character is needed at the beginning because the first CHOICE option is assigned 1, but the first character in a variable string is assigned index 0 when doing substring operations.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "choices= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
choice /c %choices:~1% /d D /t 3 /m "Choose a letter: "
set "choice=!choices:~%errorlevel%,1!"
echo you pressed %choice%
```